# Can't receive message with Zeromq PGM protocol

Tags: c#, zeromq

I'm trying to create a server/client zeromq based PUB-SUB using PGM protocol, all on my local computer.

For some reason I get stuck on:

```
string a = clientsocket.Receive(Encoding.Unicode);
```

It's just for the test and I don't get an exception, the program simply waits.

Server code:

```
var context = ZmqContext.Create();
ZmqSocket serversocket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.PUB);

try
{
    serversocket.Bind("epgm://192.168.137.127;224.0.0.1:5555");
}
catch (ZmqException)
{
    throw;
}

int x = 0;
Console.WriteLine("UP");

while (x < 100)
{
    serversocket.Send("hello",Encoding.Unicode);
    Console.WriteLine("hello sent {0}",x.ToString()); 
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    x++;
}
```

Client code:

```
context = ZmqContext.Create();
clientsocket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.SUB);

try
{
    clientsocket.Connect("epgm://192.168.137.127;224.0.0.1:5555");
}
catch (ZmqException)
{
    throw;
}

clientsocket.SubscribeAll();
clientsocket.ReceiveReady += PollingItemEvens;

string a = clientsocket.Receive(Encoding.Unicode);

if (a == "hello")
{
   Application.Run(_form1);
}

var poller = new Poller(new List<ZmqSocket> {clientsocket});

while (true)
{
    poller.Poll();
}
```

**Edit** [2014-08-04 1640 UTC+0000]

i have changed the epgm IP after reading the documentation.
yet it didnt solve the problem...

my IPv4 is `192.168.137.127`

its a hotspot seance im on a laptop, it makes any different?

and can i see the epgm on 'netstat' on windwos cmd?
because i dont see anything

Comment: I know this is an old post but I'm facing the same issue with ZMQ. Have you found any solution? what was it?

Answer (score 4):

### Pragmatic General Multicast PGM / EPGM

Uses a bit different structure for Addressing, with interface part added:

```
/* Connecting to the multicast address 224.0.0.1, port 8200,                    */
/* using the <localhost> first Ethernet network interface on Linux              */
/* and the Encapsulated PGM protocol                                            */

rc = zmq_connect( socket, "epgm://eth0;224.0.0.1:8200" );
assert ( rc == 0 );

/* Connecting to the multicast address 224.0.0.1, port 8200,                    */
/* using the <localhost> network interface setup with the address 192.168.1.1   */
/* and the standard PGM protocol                                                */

rc = zmq_connect( socket, "pgm://192.168.1.1;224.0.0.1:8200" );
assert ( rc == 0 );
```

Now check and repair the `ISO-OSI-L3` network addresses on the server side so that they match the valid local IPv4 network address, where your server resides and where it attempts to `.PUB` it's service.

**Addendum**

The 802.11 (Wi-Fi) standards specify support for multicasting as part of asynchronous services. An 802.11-client station, such as a wireless laptop or PDA (not an access point), begins a multicast delivery by sending multicast packets in 802.11 unicast data frames directed to only the access point. The access point responds with an 802.11 acknowledgement frame sent to the source station **if** no errors are found in the data frame.

If the 802.11-client sending the frame doesn't receive an acknowledgement, then the client will retransmit the frame. With multicasting, the leg of the data path from the wireless 802.11-client to the access point includes transmission error recovery. The 802.11 protocols ensure reliability between stations in both infrastructure and ad hoc configurations when using unicast data frame transmissions.

After receiving the unicast data frame from the 802.11-client, the access point transmits the data (that the originating 802.11-client wants to multicast) as a multicast frame, which contains a group address as the destination for the intended recipients. Each of the destination stations can receive the frame; however, they do not respond with acknowledgements. As a result, multicasting doesn't ensure a complete, reliable flow of data.

The lack of acknowledgements with multicasting means that some of the data your application is sending may not make it to all of the destinations, and there's no indication of a successful reception.

A note from Martin Sustrik ( co-father of ZeroMQ ):

> However, it should be noted that multicast transports are inherently 
>   complex to set up and are often fail due to inadequate networking 
>   hardware, incorrect HW/OS setup etc.

### Next step

Would be useful to post both the:

1. **Key-benefits** that made you to opt for EPGM *transportClass*
2. An application-neutral **Validation-test-case** for proving the subsequent phases of the life-cycle of each isolated parts of { ZeroMQ-layer | ZeroMQ-primitives } { are | are not } working as you expected them to.

May be inspired by: https://www.mail-archive.com/zeromq-dev@lists.zeromq.org/msg01580.html

Comment: i did the instruction. and it steel dont work..
what is the 'assert ( rc == 0 );'? i cant seem to find that command in c#

Comment: The point was in the specific [epgm] addressing <_aTransportClass_>://<_anInterface_>;<_anIpAddress_>

Comment: For `assert( { <_aPrecondition_> | <_aPostCondition_> } );` kindly check both the Wiki >>> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h and a "How-To" as a recommended practice for assertions >>> http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/assertions.html

Comment: i know the point was the epgm address. and i fixed my mistake can you look back at my original post and see if you see another mistake?

Comment: i didnt understand your EDIT can you be more specific? maybe you have an example?

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the [pgm/epgm documentation for 0MQ](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-pgm):

In particular:

> Connecting a socket
>
> When connecting a socket to a peer address using zmq_connect() with
>   the pgm or epgm transport, the endpoint shall be interpreted as an
>   interface followed by a semicolon, followed by a multicast address,
>   followed by a colon and a port number.
>
> An interface may be specified by either of the following:
>
> •The interface name as defined by the operating system.
>
> •The primary IPv4 address assigned to the interface, in its numeric representation.
>
> Interface names are not standardised in any way and should be assumed
>   to be arbitrary and platform dependent. On Win32 platforms no short
>   interface names exist, thus only the primary IPv4 address may be used
>   to specify an interface.
>
> A multicast address is specified by an IPv4 multicast address in its
>   numeric representation.

If you follow the documentation, an address of `"epgm://224.0.0.1:8200"` is invalid: it is missing the interface part of the address.

Comment: hi i took your advise and read the  doumentation and i fixed my mistake, thanks for that.

but the problem is steel the same.

if you can help i'll be grateful:
i changed the ip to:
clientsocket.Connect("epgm://192.168.137.127;224.0.0.1:8200");

Comment: @DoronEli Try to edit your question with what you &re testing now (clearly indicating you made an edit). Or post another question altogether, so people with better knowledge in 0MQ than you and me can answer ^^